# IB_DESIGNABLE and IBINSTECTABLE UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I'm trying to add a custom property to my subclass of UIImageView. The property type is of UIImageView. I have success with other data types, UIColor, int, etc. But UIImageView just doesn't appear in the custom fields of the interface builder and I can't access it via code.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface newLayerController : UIImageView

@property (nonatomic, copy) IBInspectable UIImageView *imageSheet;

  - (void)drawShape:(CGPoint)point;
  - (void)endTouch:(CGPoint)point;
  - (void)startTouch:(CGPoint)point;

@end
```

Anyone know a quick fix?

Comment: You can not have ibinspectable uiimageview. You can however have @property (nonatomic, copy) IBInspectable UIImage* image;  which in your code you can assign to the view.

Answer (score 3):

Use UIImage instead UIImageView.

```
@IBInspectable var backImage: UIImage = UIImage() {
    didSet{
        setbackImage()
    }
}

func setbackImage(){ self.image = backImage}
```